# Slack: How can i make the return text visible to anyone?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, slack

The following is the code I use to get text out of slack and write it into a google sheet.

Actually everything works perfect except the fact that the "Success" message is only seen by the person that uses the command and I couldnt find any way to make it visible to all user in the channel.

So that is also my question: How do I change this? How do I make the "Success" message visible to all users in the channel?

```
function doPost(e) {
  if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Doorbug');
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  
    //relevant data
    var parameter = e.parameter;
    var text = parameter.text;
    var userName = parameter.user_name;
    var channel = parameter.channel_name;
    var date = new Date();
    
    
    //reg-number, Email, location, UA
    var data = text.split(',');
    
    var reg = data[0];
    var email = data[1];
    var location = data[2];
    var ua = data[3];

    var slackDetails = [date, reg, email, location, ua, userName, channel];
    
    //paste the data in the sheet
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,7).setValues([slackDetails]); 
  }
  
  
  //return message for the user
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Success :)');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this Apps Script project is published as a web application and this function is being used by a Slack slash command. Please update the question providing more context if this assumption isn't correct.

If so, you want to follow [their instructions regarding message visibility when sending a response](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_immediate_response).

In particular, instead of sending a simple plain text response, you want to respond with a JSON-encoded message like this:

```
  var response = "Success :)";

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
    response_type: "in_channel",
    text: response,
  }));
```

Furthermore, you may want to reconsider the logic for crafting your response. As it stands, your function will always respond with "Success :)", even if the initial error checking evaluates to false and the function ends not inserting data into the sheet.